# How do i copyPaste through AppScript into another file instead of a sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

Right now I am using this formula to copy and paste to another Sheet. Though due to the file getting bigger and bigger, we want to place it in a seperate file which we dont really have to open.

```
function copyInfo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Kenmerken Script");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("CopyPaste");

  // get source range
  var source = copySheet.getRange(3,3,300,6);
  // get destination range
  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+2,1,500,4);

  // copy values to destination range
  source.copyTo(destination);

  // clear source values
  source.clearContent();
}
```

I tried to use getsheetbyURL instead. This did not work as it gave an error.

I also tried to find more information on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet). Though I cannot find an clear answer here.

I tried to add another "var" but "var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet. And then put pastesheet = sss.getsheetbyURL". This didnt work either.

I understand the things in the code which I have now. I only need to find the correct string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to copy `C3:H302` of a source sheet of Spreadsheet "A" to the last row of a destination sheet of Spreadsheet "B".
- You want to use Spreadsheet URL for retrieving the Spreadsheet.

In this case, when your showing script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function copyInfo() {
  var destinationSpreadsheetUrl = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet URL.
  var destinationSheetName = "###"; // Please set the destination sheet name.

  // Source sheet.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Kenmerken Script");

  // Destination sheet.
  var dstSS = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(destinationSpreadsheetUrl);
  var dstSheet = dstSS.getSheetByName(destinationSheetName);
  var temp = copySheet.copyTo(dstSS);
  temp.getRange(3, 3, 300, 6).copyTo(dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 2, 1));

  // clear source values
  copySheet.getRange(3, 3, 300, 6).clearContent();

  // Remove temp sheet.
  dstSS.deleteSheet(temp);
}
```

- When this script is run, the values of "C3:H302" are copied from the source sheet of the active Spreadsheet to the destination sheet of another Spreadsheet. And, "C3:H302" of the source sheet is cleared.
- If you want to use Spreadsheet ID, please use `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` instead of `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl()`.
- If you want to copy only the values, I thought that `getValues` and `setValues` can be also used.

#### References:

- [openByUrl(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl)
- [copyTo(spreadsheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> The formula itself works which is great. But it seems to take the formulas and not only the values. See picture: i.imgur.com/VRYCuTP.png . This causes an error since this file is not aware of any sheet named X. Would there be a way to only copy the values?
> In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function copyInfo() {
  var destinationSpreadsheetUrl = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet URL.
  var destinationSheetName = "###"; // Please set the destination sheet name.

  // Source sheet.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Kenmerken Script");
  var temp1 = copySheet.copyTo(ss);
  var r = temp1.getDataRange();
  r.copyTo(r, { contentsOnly: true });

  // Destination sheet.
  var dstSS = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(destinationSpreadsheetUrl);
  var dstSheet = dstSS.getSheetByName(destinationSheetName);
  var temp2 = temp1.copyTo(dstSS);
  temp2.getRange(3, 3, 300, 6).copyTo(dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 2, 1));

  // clear source values
  copySheet.getRange(3, 3, 300, 6).clearContent();

  // Remove temp sheets.
  ss.deleteSheet(temp1);
  dstSS.deleteSheet(temp2);
}
```

Comment: Hi Tanaike, First off. Greatly appreciate the help again! You are a good asset to this community.

The formula itself works which is great. But it seems to take the formulas and not only the values.  See picture: https://i.imgur.com/VRYCuTP.png . This causes an error since this file is not aware of any sheet named X.

Would there be a way to only copy the values?

Comment: @Scraper2022 Thank you for replying. In order to copy only the values, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike .We are now using the script with success but are seeing an issue arise. The first part of the data is a "unique identifier". We want to change it later on. 

Could there be a way to override the existing data of this unique identifier which was previously submitted?

Comment: @Scraper2022 About your new question of `We are now using the script with success but are seeing an issue arise. The first part of the data is a "unique identifier". We want to change it later on. Could there be a way to override the existing data of this unique identifier which was previously submitted?`, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. So, can I ask you about the detail of your new question? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: I think this would help you understand it. Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ht_2QMGMbHmlxSPoOiLX2vw78IL1wp3VhpOOc66eMqY/edit#gid=0

In the "Copy" we submit the data. The data will be pasted in "Data".

Here we have "Materiaal: Hout" for example. 

Now if we use "Materiaal: Hout" again in "Copy". It will be pasted in another row. Instead it needs to overwrite the current "Materiaal: Hout" found in Paste -> A2.

I hope this helps

Comment: @Scraper2022 Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot open your provided sample Spreadsheet. And, I cannot still understand your new question. But, I would like to try to understand your new question. When I could correctly understand your new question, I would like to try to think of a solution.

Comment: I gave you access. I hope this helps. If not, I can record a video to clarify.

Comment: @Scraper2022 Thank you for replying. I could open your provided sample Spreadsheet. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your new question. But I would like to support you and try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247381/discussion-between-scraper2022-and-tanaike).